# vue-test-utils finding button does not work with find option object

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

According to the [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#selectors) an element of a wrapper can be found by name.

> Using a find option object, Vue Test Utils allows for selecting elements by a name of component on wrapper components.

and the example given is

```
const buttonWrapper = wrapper.find({ name: 'my-button' })
buttonWrapper.trigger('click')
```

In my vue component I have three buttons. I want to test function of all three buttons, but  I don't want to use `wrapper.findAll("button").at(1)` to select the second button, because when the order of the buttons is changed, the test fails. So I decided to name each button and find them by name using the option object.

In my component I have:

```
<button class="button is-success" name="save-button">Opslaan</button>
```

In my test I have:

```
const button = wrappedAddSubject.find({name:"save-button"})
```

This returns `undefined` instead of the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever figure out the issue? I am facing this rn where .find() returns undefined for nested html elements

Comment: Yes, look at the comments underneath the answer. You have to specify the element and then an attribute like the name or id. For example find('input[id="description"]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "name" refers to the name of the component, not the attribute "name" of html element.

For ex, if you have a component:

```js
Vue.component('save-button', {
  template: "<button>Click</button>
})
```

you can find this component by its name using your syntax.

Comment: I don't think so. It is stated in the docs that find is not to be used to find components. The findComponent function is used to find components

Comment: It's only a deprecation warning, the "name" option used by `findComponent` is the same option used by `find`, which is to be removed. It does not change its purpose. As stated in the answer, the `name` in your code is an attribute, so you should use the appropriate selector for attributes: `find('button[name="save-button"]')`